# Slack create custom embedded video or audio player... similar to the Youtube integration

Tags: video, youtube, bots, slack-api, slack

Is it possible to create a custom website integration with Slack, similar to what Youtube has done? I have a webpage that consists of a standalone media player. I'd like Slack users to be able to use my media player directly within a slack convo when a link to my media player has been shared, similar to what Youtube has done. I don't want to force users to leave the conversation by going to a separate browser window.

Is this possible?

Here is an example of what I'm looking to do for my custom media player:

[image: Example of how I would like to embed my custom media player]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported at the moment! Only Slack's own, natively built embeds are currently possible, such as YouTube, Spotify, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is still not possible to run a custom video player within Slack, however with the [Slack App unfurling](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling) feature, you can create a similar output to the user when links to your custom video website are shared in a conversation.

So whenever a custom video link is shared in a Slack conversation, a Slack app can automatically expand that link to a preview within Slack, similar to how it works with youtube. However, for actually playing the video the user will still need to click on the link and go to the external web browser. But you can make it nice by adding a "Play" button for the link.